How can I fix react hooks in a React SSR project?
I try to migrate an existing project in js using express and ejs to render templates. I used react and react-dom. But the issues are that hooks and onChange don't work. I'm going to share the client and server code that I added to initilize the migration
This is client/index.js
import React from 'react';
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import App from './App';

hydrateRoot(document.getElementById('root'), <App />);

This is server side
react_static_path = path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist/static')
app.use('/static', express.static(react_static_path));


//
module.exports = function(req, res){
    const app_rendered = ReactDOM.renderToString(
        React.createElement(App,
        {
            location: req.url,
            context: {}
        })
    );

    fs.readFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Error');
        }

        let html_replaced = html.replace('{container}', `${app_rendered}`);

        res.send(html_replaced)
    })
}

This is the html that read before give the response
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  .a{
      background-color:#29165a;
  }
  .x-navigation li.active > a{background:#00BFB3 !important;}
  .x-navigation li > ul li.active > a{background:#00988e !important;}

</style>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/actions.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js'></script>
  <script type='text/css' src='/js/clock-picker/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation.js"></script>

   
  <link rel="icon" href="/web_images/favicons/FLETY_ICONOADMIN.png" type="image/x-icon" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/theme-default.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/map.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bs4-spacing.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />

  <style>
    #cover-spin {
      position:fixed;
      width:100%;
      left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index:9999;
      display:none;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
      to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
      to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }

    #cover-spin::after {
      content:'';
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;top:50%;
      width:40px;height:40px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-color:#29165a;
      border-top-color:transparent;
      border-width: 4px;
      border-radius:50%;
      -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
      animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
    }

    .x-navigation button,a{
      word-break: break-all;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .x-navigation a{
      padding-right: 1rem!important;
    }

    .x-navigation button:hover,.x-navigation a:hover{
      overflow: visible; 
      white-space: normal;
      height:auto;  /* just added this line */
      padding-right: 1rem!important;
    }

    .x-navigation-minimized a{
      overflow: unset !important;
    }

    .hide_long_text{
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

  </style>
   
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div id="root">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

I hope that can help me with this
I tried to using another hydrate template like createRoot from react-dom/client, but didn't work

Where are "hooks and onChang"?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
